# error 1 cocos2d x libgame.so

Tags: android, cygwin, cocos2d-x

I have been trying for last 2 days to compile a helloworld project for android. It had been giving different errors so far but I found my way through using the different questions asked here by users or at stackoverflow. But now, I have searched everywhere and couldn't find a proper solution anywhere.

When I try to run the build_native.sh in cygwin, it starts compiling but in the libgame.so shared library, it gives an error with exit code 1. Other guys have been getting this type of errors but none of their solution work for me. 
I have checked the android.mk and the references are the correct.

Every way I tried has failed. I need serious help :(

Thanks a lot :)

P.S I am using windows8 (64 bit).

Comment: try to follow this procedure. I guess you might have followed  jesususboach's article ..  http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/How_to_run_HelloWorld_on_ndk_r4_and_r5

Comment: if above procedure will not work then try to build with eclipse rather than going for cygwin

Comment: can you please paste the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys, Had it figured out right away, will post the answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't set up the paths in the main.c file. It needed to be pointed to the right folder (classes) Unfortunately no article or tutorial mentioned it, managed it by trial and error.

Comment: which path ? where the main.c file is located ?